# SFTP Upload/Sync on Save Plugin for Eclipse Luna for PHP Developers

Tags: php, eclipse, sftp, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-luna

I was using the Eclipse-SFTP (http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-sftp) plugin with Kepler and it worked perfectly. Unfortunately, since upgrading to Luna, I have lost the Upload on Save capability. I am aware I can use native eclipse RSE to manage releases, but I need something which will auto upload on save to our dev server for testing.

I am also aware of the Aptana Plugin, but I would like to avoid installing this if possible as I was wanting to utilize the features in Eclipse for PHP Developers edition.

Thanks in advance.